# how to get the "ajax-sending-filename" in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is there a possibility to get the name of the file witch is sending a post/get to my php.file via ajax.

Or do I have to pass the filename via javascript?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "filename" sending an AJAX request because the call to your PHP file takes places inside the client's browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
By using PHP

<?php 

//you'll get file name
echo $_FILES['field_name']['name'];


?>

<script>
//you will get the full path
alert($('field_id').val());
```

//this will fetch your field value
    var value =$('field_id').val();

```
 //this will identifies your last / in that value 
    var file_name = value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('/')+(value.length-value.lastIndexOf('/')));


</script>
```